How do I upload files with Arduino 2.0?
I am going down a bit of a rabbit hole but as far as I can tell the LittleFS module has been included in arduino-esp32
It seems that is the newer version of this.
So it looks like it should be in my Arduino as long as I have ESP32 installed which I do, however, when I try to create a ./data folder with an index.html and the following in my .ino
#include <FS.h>
#include <LittleFS.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WebServer.h>

WebServer server(80);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(1000); // Give time for the serial monitor to start

  if(!LittleFS.begin(true)) {
    Serial.println("LittleFS Mount Failed");
    return;
  }

  WiFi.begin("BroadviewOnline", "BuckeyeGuy");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi...");
  }
  Serial.println("Connected to WiFi");
  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  server.on("/", HTTP_GET, []() {
    Serial.println("Page requested: /");
    File file = LittleFS.open("/index.html", "r");
    if (!file) {
      Serial.println("Failed to open file");
      server.send(500, "text/plain", "Internal Server Error");
      return;
    }
    size_t fileSize = file.size();
    Serial.print("File size: ");
    Serial.println(fileSize);
    if (fileSize > 0) {
      server.streamFile(file, "text/html");
    } else {
      Serial.println("File is empty");
      server.send(500, "text/plain", "Internal Server Error");
    }
    file.close();
  });

  server.begin();
  Serial.println("HTTP server started");
}

void loop() {
  server.handleClient();
  delay(10); // Yield to reset the watchdog timer
}

I get an empty response at the IP like the file never go uploaded. What am I missing?

For now my TLDR is to use Platform.io instead of the Arduino plugin.
